# How to configure SUMA in AIX

Tags: aix

I need to configure or install [SUMA](http://www-03.ibm.com/systems/power/software/aix/whitepapers/suma.html).  What is the procedure and steps to do this?  I am very new to AIX.

Answer (score 1):

As a new comer to AIX you are probably best off using smit, the menu driven config utility for AIX.

Run `smit suma` to invoke the suma part of smit, remember you need a fairly large volume group for item storage (at least 4Gb).

Comment: when i type the command "summa" im getting the following error,

so i think suma is not configured properly,


Can't locate LibExt/CatGetS.pm in @INC (@INC contains: /usr/suma/lib /usr/opt/perl5/lib/5.8.2/aix-thread-multi /usr/opt/perl5/lib/5.8.2 /usr/opt/perl5/lib/site_perl/5.8.2/aix-thread-multi /usr/opt/perl5/lib/site_perl/5.8.2 /usr/opt/perl5/lib/site_perl .) at /usr/suma/lib/SUMA/Messenger.pm line 200, <$fh> line 101

Comment: Looks like someone has messed around with the perl install on that machine, check if you can change the $PATH around so the stock perl is first.

Comment: Hi thanks, im a new beei to AIX can u pls tell me how to change the $PATH